# How to merge/combine multiple result sets in stored procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, merge

I have 3 stored procedure in MySQL db. I cannot merged/combined all of them in to one result sets. UNION, JOIN are not works. Create temp table as well. But when I run merged procedure it's always shows only first procedure result sets.

My stored procedures 1st have a parameter that I can change before I run it.

```
call ftht_away(1);
call ftht_home(1);
call ftht_table(1);
```

My 3 procedures:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE  PROCEDURE `first_half_table`(IN league INT)
BEGIN
SELECT
`t`.`league_id` AS `league_id`,
tot.Team AS League,
SUM(tot.P) AS P,
SUM(tot.W) AS W,
SUM(tot.D) AS D,
SUM(tot.L) AS L,
SUM(tot.F) AS F,
SUM(tot.A) AS A,
SUM(tot.GD) AS GD,
SUM(tot.PTS) AS Pts
FROM
((SELECT
htft2.home AS Team,
1 AS P,
IF((htft2.home_ht_result > htft2.away_ht_result), 1, 0) AS W,
IF((htft2.home_ht_result = htft2.away_ht_result), 1, 0) AS D,
IF((htft2.home_ht_result < htft2.away_ht_result), 1, 0) AS L,
htft2.home_ht_result AS F,
htft2.away_ht_result AS A,
(htft2.home_ht_result - htft2.away_ht_result) AS GD,
(CASE
WHEN (htft2.home_ht_result > htft2.away_ht_result) THEN 3
WHEN (htft2.home_ht_result = htft2.away_ht_result) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) AS PTS
FROM
htft2 UNION ALL SELECT
htft2.away AS away,
1 AS '1',
IF((htft2.home_ht_result < htft2.away_ht_result), 1, 0) AS 'IF(home_ht_result < away_ht_result,1,0)',
IF((htft2.home_ht_result = htft2.away_ht_result), 1, 0) AS 'IF(home_ht_result = away_ht_result,1,0)',
IF((htft2.home_ht_result > htft2.away_ht_result), 1, 0) AS 'IF(home_ht_result > away_ht_result,1,0)',
htft2.away_ht_result AS away_ht_result,
htft2.home_ht_result AS home_ht_result,
(htft2.away_ht_result - htft2.home_ht_result) AS 'GD',
(CASE
WHEN (htft2.home_ht_result < htft2.away_ht_result) THEN 3
WHEN (htft2.home_ht_result = htft2.away_ht_result) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) AS 'CASE'
FROM
htft2) tot
JOIN teams2023 t ON ((tot.Team = CONVERT( t.team_name USING UTF8MB4))))
WHERE
(t.league_id = league)
GROUP BY tot.Team, t.league_id 
ORDER BY SUM(tot.PTS) DESC , GD DESC;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `fh_away`(IN league INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        `t`.`league_id` AS `league_id`,
        `tot`.`Team` AS `League`,
        SUM(`tot`.`P`) AS `P`,
        SUM(`tot`.`W`) AS `W`,
        SUM(`tot`.`D`) AS `D`,
        SUM(`tot`.`L`) AS `L`,
        SUM(`tot`.`F`) AS `F`,
        SUM(`tot`.`A`) AS `A`,
        SUM(`tot`.`GD`) AS `GD`,
        SUM(`tot`.`PTS`) AS `Pts`
    FROM
        ((SELECT 
            `htft2`.`away` AS `Team`,
                1 AS `P`,
                IF((`htft2`.`home_ht_result` > `htft2`.`away_ht_result`), 1, 0) AS `L`,
                IF((`htft2`.`home_ht_result` = `htft2`.`away_ht_result`), 1, 0) AS `D`,
                IF((`htft2`.`home_ht_result` < `htft2`.`away_ht_result`), 1, 0) AS `W`,
                `htft2`.`away_ht_result` AS `F`,
                `htft2`.`home_ht_result` AS `A`,
                (`htft2`.`away_ht_result` - `htft2`.`home_ht_result`) AS `GD`,
                (CASE
                    WHEN (`htft2`.`home_ht_result` < `htft2`.`away_ht_result`) THEN 3
                    WHEN (`htft2`.`home_ht_result` = `htft2`.`away_ht_result`) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END) AS `PTS`
        FROM
            `htft2`) `tot`
        JOIN `teams2023` `t` ON ((`tot`.`Team` = CONVERT( `t`.`team_name` USING UTF8MB4))))
    WHERE
(t.league_id = league)
GROUP BY tot.Team, t.league_id 
    ORDER BY SUM(`tot`.`PTS`) DESC , `GD` DESC;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fh_home`(IN league INT)
BEGIN
SELECT 
        `t`.`league_id` AS `league_id`,
        `tot`.`Team` AS `League`,
        SUM(`tot`.`P`) AS `P`,
        SUM(`tot`.`W`) AS `W`,
        SUM(`tot`.`D`) AS `D`,
        SUM(`tot`.`L`) AS `L`,
        SUM(`tot`.`F`) AS `F`,
        SUM(`tot`.`A`) AS `A`,
        SUM(`tot`.`GD`) AS `GD`,
        SUM(`tot`.`PTS`) AS `Pts`
    FROM
        ((SELECT 
            `htft2`.`home` AS `Team`,
                1 AS `P`,
                IF((`htft2`.`home_ht_result` > `htft2`.`away_ht_result`), 1, 0) AS `W`,
                IF((`htft2`.`home_ht_result` = `htft2`.`away_ht_result`), 1, 0) AS `D`,
                IF((`htft2`.`home_ht_result` < `htft2`.`away_ht_result`), 1, 0) AS `L`,
                `htft2`.`home_ht_result` AS `F`,
                `htft2`.`away_ht_result` AS `A`,
                (`htft2`.`home_ht_result` - `htft2`.`away_ht_result`) AS `GD`,
                (CASE
                    WHEN (`htft2`.`home_ht_result` > `htft2`.`away_ht_result`) THEN 3
                    WHEN (`htft2`.`home_ht_result` = `htft2`.`away_ht_result`) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END) AS `PTS`
        FROM
            `htft2`) `tot`
        JOIN `teams2023` `t` ON ((`tot`.`Team` = CONVERT( `t`.`team_name` USING UTF8MB4))))
    WHERE
(t.league_id = league)
GROUP BY tot.Team, t.league_id 
    ORDER BY SUM(`tot`.`PTS`) DESC , `GD` DESC;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D0yB.png)

[SP1,2,3 picture and combined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3zpm.png)

Comment: The rowsets produced by SP (yes, SP may produce a collection of rowsets) cannot be used as rowsource. Modify your SPs, insert the data produced in them into static or temporary table(s) with some pre-defined name(s) then query these tables and obtain final result.

Comment: If it is possible can you pls. write final query? I can’t make it as you mention. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Modify your stored procedures. In each procedure replace the former `SELECT` with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE total_data_N SELECT`, where `N` is SP number.
2. Create stored procedure which will perform all additional actions:

   - call all your SPs one-by-one
   - select collected data
   - drop temptables

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_total_data (IN league INT)
BEGIN
  CALL ftht_away(league);
  CALL ftht_home(league);
  CALL ftht_table(league);
  SELECT * 
    FROM total_data_1
    JOIN total_data_2 USING (league_id, league)
    JOIN total_data_3 USING (league_id, league);
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE total_data_1;
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE total_data_2;
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE total_data_3;
END
```

3. Execute created procedure by `CALL get_total_data(1);`, and it will produced combined rowset which you need in.

[simplified DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ru5G8jXo)

Comment: Thank you. This way it worked separately. So I got 3 result pages. How can I combine them side by side in a single result table? (Like using union etc.)

Comment: @TechnoBAKKAL *So I got 3 result pages.* ??? Have you edited SPs codes according to paragraph 1? If you do this then you must obtain one solid rowset (like using UNION).

Comment: Yes sure. But when I CALL get_total_data(1); it's giving each SPs in different result outputs in MySQL Workbench application. Does not combined all in one result. How can I modify your query with using UNOION? Can you do it for me please?

Comment: @TechnoBAKKAL You have **NOT** implemented the modifications according #1. Your separate SPs executes common SELECT whereas they must insert selected rows into temptable without producing any output at all.

Comment: @TechnoBAKKAL DEMO added.

Comment: I added picture to end of my issue. Like in picture, how can I see results like that?

Comment: @TechnoBAKKAL I.e. you want to combine `(league_id, league)` from each rowset and attach another columns separately for the same pair value? if so then modify your SPs, create separate temptable and fill them with separate data in each SP, and in outer SP join these 3 temptables and produce needed rowset.

Comment: I added new picture to my issue. I described what I need. Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and helpful approach. Your final edits worked perfectly and the way I wanted. Kind regards.